# Darken Libgdx Tiled Map

Tags: java, libgdx

I am new to Libgdx and am doing a game prototype with a certain features. One of which I am unable to achieve at the moment is to darken the map such that my character can "glow" in the dark map.

**Before Blending Output:**
[image: Before Darkening]

Currently, I load my map using `TiledMap` and `TiledMapRenderer`.

Load my map:

```
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/ascent/ascent.tmx");
float unitScale = 2f;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, unitScale);
```

In my `render()` method:

```java
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Run the playMovement Method
        player1Movement(playerHashMap.get(p1), delta);

        // Draw the Map
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        // Set the brightness and blend function
        float lightness = .1f;
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(lightness,lightness,lightness,1f);
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().enableBlending();
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);

        // Begin Batch drawing
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().begin();

        // Draw the light
        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().draw(light, p1.box.x - 25f, p1.box.y - 25f, 80, 80);

        // Draw the player
        playerHashMap.forEach((player, input) -> player.draw(tiledMapRenderer.getBatch()));

        tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().end();
    }
```

**My attempt at blending:**
[image: My attempt]

I tried blending and is unable to darken my surroundings map.

**Qn:** Is there any way to darken a TiledMap?

I would like to thank you all in advance for your advice for your help !

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use these tiled maps, but don't you render the tiled map and then clear the screen before drawing your light? If you clear the screen after you've rendered your tiled map, it's not surprising you don't see the tiled map.

Comment: Yes, I soon realise why the tiled map didn’t load and its pitch black as I clear it! I will update the question again to get a clearer picture !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the batch that renders the map and apply a tint before drawing. The tint would darken by reducing all the RGB values (or lightening etc).

```
final float darken =0.5f;
tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().setColor(darken,darken,darken,1f);
```

and then you don't need to set the clear color and blend.
Yes, `setColor` should be called `setTint` !!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ! May I ask, is i use the `tiledMapRenderer.getBatch()` to set the Tint. Does it mean, my batch that draws the light and character have to be a different batch?
After setting `tiledMapRenderer.getBatch().setColor(darken,darken,darken,1f);` my player and light also darken as well

Comment: Basically yes. However, you can reuse the same batch, so when you say ```getBatch().end()``` that would "flush" the current content of the batch , with the specified tint. You can then ```begin``` again and specify a different tint for the next use of the batch. So the tint is not per batch, but per -use- of the batch. So one begin-end pair for your background and another begin-end pair for the character.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I follow your method by reusing the same `batch` and use `getBatch.end();`. 
However, as soon as I being the new `getBatch().begin();` and set the color `.getBatch().setColor(Color.WHITE);` The begin-end pair for my background got updated to White too. 

Am I missing some stuff here?

Comment: This is what I did thus far: https://pastebin.com/kvP1Cjba

Comment: Try ```getBatch().flush()```  before starting the second use of the batch, which should write out the contents. If that doesn't help you may need to use a different ```OrthogonalTiledRenderer``` for each layer.

Comment: Thank you for much. `getBatch().flush()` could not work. I have to use a different `OrthogonalTiledRenderer`

Comment: I am pretty sure thats going to be it. However, you could go here, libGDX discord server,  https://discord.gg/6pgDK9F and post in the help channel.