# Android Studio using LibGDX batch.setColor isn't using rgba value I give it

Tags: android

Basically I'm drawing a cat, I have layered different patterns in their own sprites to get a variety of colours and patterns. It layers as I want but the colour is not changing from original sprite.

`batch.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GREY)` works but if I want a custom colour like `batch.setColor(new Color(76,46,23,1))` or just `batch.setColor(76,46,23,1)` it does nothing.

However if I give any of rgb 255 or 0 it does change, for example `batch.setColor(0,255,255,1)` gives me a bright cyan colour as expected. It's any number between 0 & 255 that seems to be the problem. I've tried using `sprite.setColor()` too and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask on the discord forum about this and also see https://libgdx.com/news/2021/06/colorful-gdx for the kind of absolute colouring you are after but essentially the issue is that `setColor` should really be called `setTint` because its a multiplier not an absolute setter.
See here also
[Darken Libgdx Tiled Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022287/darken-libgdx-tiled-map/66040489#66040489)